# ReqlDriverError while connecting to rethinkdb in Django

Tags: django, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

Django throws below error :

```
ReqlDriverError: Server dropped connection with message: "RethinkDB cluster"
```

Am trying to connect to RethinkDB in Django via custom middleware.

Below is the code am using to connect to RethinkDB

```
@singleton
class rDBMiddleware(object):
    connection = None
   def __init__(self):
      if self.connection == None:
     self.connection = r.connect(host=' 192.x.x.x ', port=29015, db=' re_test ').repl()
```

Could you help me to figure this out ? I couldn't find any solution in the Internet so far on this ReqlDriverError.

I am able to connect/access the RethinkDB server via http:/x.x.x.x:8080/

Using python2.7, and rethinkdb (2.1.0.post2) driver in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`29015` is the port for RethinkDB intracluster communication.  You probably want to connect the driver to port `28015`.

Comment: To help out those coming here from Google, if you try and use the JS client on this port it will throw `ReqlDriverError: RethinkDB cluster`

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved.

replaced connection with below line:

self.connection = r.connect('192.x.x.x',28015).repl()